# Auto populating input boxes from filter in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hi I have following form in which I have two input boxes and a ng-repeat that displays the results. Basically in my controller it fetches data from db and is loaded in the nt-repeat.

```
 <td>
     <div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="item.logo">

      </div> </td>

      <td>
         <div>
           <input type="text" ng-model="item.name" >

         </div>
      </td>


 <tr ng-repeat="aa in addlaborrates | filter:{name:item.name} ">
              <td>{{aa.name}}</td>
              <td>{{aa.lago}}</td>
             <td>{{aa.id}}</td>
  </tr>
```

When i type in the item.name input box filter finds the matching items in the ng-repeat.
What i am trying to do is when I type in name input box as it filters I want the logo fields also be auto populated with corresponding value. Please let me know how to achieve this. 
Thanks

Comment: You have written 'logo' wrongly: <td>{{aa.lago}}</td>, is that what you mean? or maybe you want to filter also by logo: http://jsfiddle.net/V9bgn/

Comment: @QuarK So like in your example if i type something in first box i am trying to have corresponding second box be filled while typing in first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a filter like in http://jsfiddle.net/V9bgn/1/

```
.filter('getLogo', function() {
  return function(array, value) {
    var ret = [];
    angular.forEach(array, function(item) {
        if (item.name.indexOf(value) > -1) {
            ret.push(item.logo);
        }
    });

    return ret[0] || '';
  };    
});
```

And then use it in the controller:

```
$scope.$watch('item.name', function(val) {
    $scope.item.logo = $filter('getLogo')($scope.addlaborrates,val);
});
```